# Как в cocoa api конвертировать bit rate в вид для пользователя?

Tags: swift, xcode, objective-c, macos, cocoa

Всем доброго времени суток!

Вопрос  состоит в следующем:

С помощью `NSMetaDataItem` я получаю из аудио файла AudioBitRate и SampleRate:

```
NSMetadataItem *metadata = [[NSMetadataItem alloc] initWithURL:[element url]];
NSNumber *sampleRate = [metadata valueForAttribute:NSMetadataItemAudioSampleRateKey];

NSMetadataItem *metadata = [[NSMetadataItem alloc] initWithURL:[element url]];
NSNumber *bitRate = [metadata valueForAttribute:NSMetadataItemAudioSampleRateKey];
```

полученные данные представляют из себя, я так понимаю, число бит в секунду.

Мне нужно эти биты перевести в читабельный формат для пользователя, например число 260751 представить в виде 260.8 KBit/s .

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли в Cocoa класс для представления битрейта в читабельный вид на подобии `NSByteCountFormatter`?

Или как можно форматировать битрейт в вид для пользователя?

Всех заранее благодарю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это несложно. Пишете простой конвертер.

```
class BitrateConverter: NSObject {
    static let sharedBitrateConverter = BitrateConverter()

    func convertBitrateToKBitPerSecs (bitrate: NSNumber) -> String {
        let bitrateInt = bitrate.intValue

        let bitrateDouble: Double = Double(bitrateInt)/1000
        let result: String = String(format: "%.1f KBit/s", bitrateDouble)

        return result
    }
}
```

И используете его:

```
let testBitrate: NSNumber = NSNumber(value: 260751)
let result = BitrateConverter.sharedBitrateConverter.convertBitrateToKBitPerSecs(bitrate: testBitrate) // выведет 260.8 KBit/s
```